# would you mind answers

Tags: word-meaning

Please give me the correction if the answers of this question are wrong. The question  :  Would you mind staying at home?

Answers:
A. Yes, I would (meaning "I don't want to stay at home).
B. No, I would not (meaning " That's fine. I want to stay at home)
C. I'd rather not (meaning "  I want to leave, I don't want to stay at home)

Answer (score 1):

The examples you gave will be easily understood by native speakers as you intended. If, however, you are worried about even the slightest ambiguity, do not condense your sentences by relying only on a modal verb rather than a modal verb coupled with a verb that carries specific meaning.

**Yes, I would mind** has no potential for ambiguity.

**No, I wouldn't mind** has no potential for ambiguity.

**I'd rather not stay home** has no potential for ambiguity.

I repeat that a native speaker is extremely unlikely to find your examples ambiguous, but if the choice is between clarity and concision, go for clarity.